# jQuery - submit on return for one form disabling submit on return for another form

Tags: jquery, forms, submit, multiple-forms

I have a page with more than one form. One form (see below example) has an input to add rows to a table on the page. Each of the rows in the table can be selected (checkbox) on/off. The other form submits the page sending which rows were "on" to the next page.

So, the initial problem was that people were entering a url and clicking return to add it to the table, but instead is was not adding it, but submitting the 'other' form (mainForm).

So, I added the jQuery below. That fixed the problem -- now, when the url field is in focus and you click return it adds a url to the list and does not submit the mainForm.

However, when that field is NOT in focus, pressing return does nothing - when I expected it to submit the form (the default behavior) ... since the event is only attached to that one input field.

HTML (greatly simplified):

```
<form name="data>
 <input id="url" class="field" type="text" size="65" name="urlText">
 <input class="hubField" type="button" value="Add Url" name="urlAddButton">
 <table>
    <tr>
       <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
       <td>Description text</td>
       ....and so on...
 </table>
</form>

<form name="mainForm">
 <input type="SUBMIT" value="Load Selected Urls" name="Submit">
</form>
```

JS/jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#url').bind('keyup',function(e) {
        if (e.which == 13) {
        $('input[name="urlAddButton"]').focus().click();
        e.preventDefault();
        }
    })
});
```

I'm fairly new to jQuery, so be nice. ;-)  In js I'd probably just write something saying if that field is not in focus and return is pressed, submit main form. Is there a trick to do this easier in JQuery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand, you want to submit the mainForm when a user press enter while he's **not** in the "url" input. When he's in, you trigger the click on "urlAddButton". If so, here is a working example on jsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/MUUUE/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(this).bind('keydown',function(e) {//keyDOWN (for the input)
        if(e.which == 13) {//if enter is pressed
            if(e.target.id == "url"){//and we're in the url input
                 $('input[name="urlAddButton"]').focus().click();
                 e.preventDefault();
            }
            else if(e.target.type != "textarea" && e.target.type != "text"){//else, we submit the main form (if we're not in another input or textarea)
                $("#mainForm").submit();//id attr added in the html code
            }
        }
    })
});
```

But, in the end, I'm not sure that it's so good to submit a form while you're not in an input.

Answer (score 0):

Give the form you want to submit an id ("mainform") and then use `$('#mainform').submit();` I do realize you can target that form based on the name attribute, but using an id is much faster, provided you have control over the markup.

Check out the docs for more. - http://api.jquery.com/submit/ and the sample they give

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#url').bind('keyup',function(e) {
        if (e.which == 13) {
            $('#mainform').submit();
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    })
});
```